# Save path globally in php site?

Tags: php, session-variables, state, web-testing

Currently I have a website written in php. I am placing a full version of the site in separate directory (e.g. test001, test002) for test purposes...

The initialization file `init.php` is required in all the webcode files, with the following line:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test002/init.php';
```

However, when I change the test directory I have to modify this line in all the files... I looking for a way to save the path to `init.php`, to be able to change it only once.

- How can I achieve that ?
- Do I have to use `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: you could try `require_once( __DIR__ . "\init.php" );` perhaps

Comment: You could use the auto_prepend_file php.ini config option you could define in an htaccess file but -- it would be a bad practice but it would allow you to include a file easily for all your files.

Answer (score 1):

Session is not a good solution for this . you can create a config file. then you can include like this 
**config.php**

```
$file=dirname(__FILE__).'/test002/init.php'; 
include($file);
```

in other php files

```
include('config.php');
```

and call config file on all files you need . like this you just need to change path in config file

Comment: @grigory's problem is if he change the directory he needs to change path in all the files where it includes. with config file he needs to change the include directory only in config file. whats wrong ?

Comment: In modern PHP you can also just use `__DIR__` rather than `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Alas @Will - again you have the `test002` element to the path - that's not needed nor is it going to work

Comment: @ShowStopper if he has file let say /test002/somedir/somedir2/test.php and its call at browser will your code work ?

Comment: offcourse it will work . change the path in config file only . you don't need to change in all php files

Answer (score 1):

If each of the folders (`test001`,`test002` etc ) have the `init.php` file and if each `init.php` is different then you could use the magic constant `__DIR__`

```
require_once( __DIR__ . "\init.php" );
```

If the `init.php` is the same throughout the various test folders then it might be better to put `init.php` outwith these folders somewhere and use a common include path.

```
set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/' );
require_once( 'init.php' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Old working way:

```
require_once('init.php'); 
//This is for all files in the same directory 

require_once('../init.php');
//This is for all files in a directory 1 lvl under the init.

require_once('../../init.php');
//This is for all files in a directory 2 lvl under the init. .. And so on
```

There is no point to use anything else if all files are in 1 base directory (eg. test001, test002...)

Comment: Fair enough, but I also want to move file to different directories and don't think about this line.. i still need to think should i use '../init.php' or '../../init.php'...

Comment: If you move the file you have to fix all places where you require it. Movement is equal to renaming and if you rename it to newinit.php you have to fix it of course..

Comment: If you move the site into a new test006 folder this will be working, if you change some file directory test.php > new/test.php you have to add ../ as it is inside 1 directory. You are making manual change and you have to fix the path the same way.

Comment: Yes, exactly... in case i want to rearrange my code files in different directories it can be a headache...

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that such rearrange can/should be often.. 
Another way is by using 1 index.php to access all your pages but its something really different..

Answer (score 0):

Make `congig.php` file and define constants as follows.

```
<?php

 $web_path = "test002/init.php";  

 define('PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

   new_path = PATH.'/'.$web_path; 

?>
```